# Building URL, determining http/s

Tags: php, url

First I would like to let you guys know that I am no expert in PHP, I know some basics. I am learning by myself, this is why I am turning to you guys for help.

I made some search but in vein, I can't figure out what should I search for.

Line of code from a whole block

```
$base_root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 'https' : 'http';
```

So the block of code is for building the url. This line of code choose if its either http or https.

```
(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')
```

This line checks if https is set. Until now its ok

```
 ? 'https' : 'http';
```

This is where I need help. What does the '?' and ':' does?

Thanks in advance.
Also it would be great if you guys could recommend me some books, sites or tutorials where I can learn.

Kind Regards

Comment: wow great, thanks. there are a lot of other operators I needed to search for. THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's shorthand for if - else combo

`statement ? code 1 : code 2`

is equivalent to

`if( statement ) {
 code 1
} else {
 code 2
}`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

It is the [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

It returns the value between `?` and `:` if the condition in front of the `?` is `true`. And the value after the `:` if the condition is `false`.

I recommend reading the PHP manual in general, it gives lots of information on almost any topic regarding PHP.

Comment: thanks. but there are a lot of stuff in it, should I read the whole documentations?

Comment: @OuzKedz You should read the [language reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) at least. It gives information on basic use. It is probably impossible to read the whole function documention, I recommend searching for a proper method in case you need one and reading the appropriate manual afterwards.

Comment: @OuzKedz - I suggest you read it as you need it. But the [Language Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php) chapter is worth an afternoon, esp. from "Basic syntax" to "Control Structures".

Answer (score 0):

This is ternary conditional operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$base_root = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') 

? 'https' : 'http';
this is like if else statement if above line is true then $base_root will assigned with 'https'(which is just after ?) if it is false then it will get assigned with 'http'(which is after :)
```

just check below condition you will get understand easily...

```
if((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')){
    $base_root = 'https';
}else{
    $base_root = 'http';
}
```